# C++ making min and max function for vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I am trying to develop a minimum and maximum function for a vector of doubles.
I am using iterators to go through the vector to find the min and max values. My code works, however, if the value I am trying to return is at the end of the list, the function won't return it.
I have used the same for loop on the ostream operator and that has worked fine however it doesn't work for these functions. Am I missing something?

```
double maximum() {
    double maximum;
    typedef vector<double>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter i = this->get_data().begin(); i != this->get_data().end(); ++i) {
        if (*i > maximum) {
             maximum = *i;

        } else {
             return maximum;
        }
    }
}
```

Side Note: The get_data function is one I created in the class that this method is in which returns a vector of doubles

Comment: use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`

Comment: The variable `maximum` is not initialized. Better set it to something really small.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I did know about those, but I wanted to see if I could make my own =)

Comment: @NickKaraolis Hmm... I see a potential flaw in this code, above and beyond finding the maximum.  What exactly does `get_data()` do?  Can you post it?  If it returns a vector by value, then you've got trouble...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie const vector<double> &get_data() const { 
return samp;
}

Comment: @NickKaraolis - May I suggest you save that value in a variable, and use it in the for-loop construct.  This way, the code doesn't have the smell of using a different vector in the `for` loop construct.

Comment: @NickKaraolis - `const vector<double>& tempV = get_data();...for(iter i = tempV.begin(); i != tempV.end(); ++i )`  This is what should be done, to ease the suspicion of using differing iterators in the for-loop.  If you changed that code to return the vector by value, you will still be ok with the code change I suggested -- you would have *not* been ok if you stuck with your original code.

Comment: You need to initialize. `maximum` to `std::numeric_limits<double>::min` and remove the spurious  `else` for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'll preface this by saying that in production code I would always use [`std::min_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) to avoid problems in implementation like the one you are facing. Doing this as a learning exercise is a good idea though! The problem you have here is that the return is in the wrong place:

```
#include <limits>
double maximum() {
    double maximum = std::numeric_limits<double>::min();//This is important
    typedef vector<double>::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter i = this->get_data().begin(); i != this->get_data().end(); ++i) {
        if (*i > maximum) {
            maximum = *i; 
        } else {
            // the first time you get a number less than the
            // current maximum you are returning immediately!
            return maximum;
        }
    }
    //return maximum should be here
}
```

Remove the entire else branch (it's unnecessary) and move the return to after the for loop has examined all the elements.
Also you want to initialize maximum to be the minimum number that can be stored in a double, the [numeric_limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/) is of help here. Currently you are using `maximum` without first assigning it a value so if the value that happened to be stored in `maximum` was bigger than your elements then you will get the wrong result. Don't leave this to chance, always initialize your variables.

Comment: Also, initialize that maximum.

Comment: @shuttle87 yes that did make the difference, thanks for the help

Comment: @mguerri, very good point! I missed that the first time around so I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are well-defined algorithms for this purpose:-

```
std::min_element
std::max_element
```

Comment: @marsh - But there is no mention that the OP is aware of the algorithm functions, and may wind up being very glad that they don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I knew about those functions, I just wanted to try and do it without using them. Thanks for the heads up though

Answer (score 1):

Your code is in error. Drop the `else` clause and move the `return` to after the `for` loop.

```
double maximum() {
    double maximum; // need to initialize this as well
    typedef vector<double>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter i = this->get_data().begin(); i != this->get_data().end(); ++i) {
        if (*i > maximum) {
             maximum = *i;
        }
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

You could use the first element as the initial value and assume the `vector` is non-empty. If you do this you might also start the loop at the second element.

Otherwise, you haven't defined what the behavior should be on an empty `vector`. You could also initialize `maximum` to negative infinity or `MIN_DOUBLE` and not assume the vector is empty. This value is also equivalent to the `std::numeric_limits<double>::min()`.

Whenever you write a loop, it is best to think of the invariants that you want to maintain. In this case the variant is the element of the vector pointed to by `i`. The invariant is that `maximum` contains the maximum value of the vector.

As soon as you say that out loud, it becomes obvious that the empty vector must be handled as a special case. What is the maximum of an empty vector? I don't know. It is undefined. We can make up a value, but that should be documented. Alternatively this could be an error.

Once you've decided how to handle this case, it is apparent that you must process all elements to know the maximum. Thus you cannot exit the loop early. That's why the `return` was wrong.

The next step is determining which element is maximal. This part you got mostly right. When `*i` is greater than `maximum` you have a new maximal element. Thus you need a conditional check and assignment.

Doing this type of analysis for every loop you ever write will save you many bugs.

Answer (score 0):

- First at all you need to initialize the maximum variable. A good
  value would be the first element of the vector.
- Than the else statement is unnecessary and very wrong. Drop it from the for loop,
  and move the return to the end of function. Otherwise it will return
  the first value which is not higher than its previous element in the
  vector.